# How do I save 4 GB+ files on a FAT32 flash drive?

Tags: filesystems, fat32

I have a 6 GB file that I want to move to my flash drive. The only problem is that the limitations of FAT32 prevent me. I would like to avoid NTFS. I also can't use exFAT because I would then have difficulty booting from it. It's already fully compressed, so I can't make it any smaller.

Is there a way to work around this limitation?